# Angularjs call synchronization

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I am using angularjs get method to get array of feeds from server. here is my controller code.

```
$scope.feeds = new Array();

    $scope.feeds = FeedService.getFeeds();
    console.debug("in controller : "+$scope.feeds);
```

and my FeedService code is

```
getFeeds : function (){
            $http.get('/app/get').success(function(response){
                                console.debug(response);                    
                                 return response;

            }).error(function(){
                console.debug("failed");
            });
        }
```

in firbug console i am getting `undefined` for `$scope.feeds` while in `FeedbackService` it is printing the json object. I know that i am getting `undefined` because of the code is synchronous. What can i do to handle the problem. My html is

```
<div ng-repeat = "feed in feeds">
    <feed feed-text={{feed.feedText}} feed-user={{feed.user}}></feed>
</div>
```

I am not getting printed any thing on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to return a promise from your `$http` call, then resolve it in your controller and bind a scope property to the response:

```
getFeeds : function (){
        return $http.get('/app/get');
    }

// in controller:

Feedservice.getFeeds().then(function(promise){
   $scope.feeds = promise.data;
})
```

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend http://egghead.io as a great resource of video tutorials on the topic of angular. He explains the concept around promises better than i ever could :)